# Oracle SQL Query for Stacked Pareto Chart

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pareto-chart

I have an Oracle Table that contains data similar to the following basic example:

```
+--------+----------+
| SERIES | CATEGORY |
+--------+----------+
| green  | apple    |
| green  | pear     |
| green  | pear     |
| yellow | apple    |
| yellow | apple    |
| yellow | pear     |
| yellow | pear     |
| yellow | pear     |
| yellow | banana   |
| yellow | banana   |
| yellow | banana   |
| red    | apple    |
+--------+----------+
```

I would like to generate a Pareto-like Graph of this data that should look as like Stacked Pareto Chart,

[image]

To create this graph I would like to run a SQL query and get the following output:

```
+----------+--------+-------+
| CATEGORY | SERIES | COUNT |
+----------+--------+-------+
| pear     | green  |     2 |
| pear     | yellow |     3 |
| apple    | green  |     1 |
| apple    | yellow |     2 |
| apple    | red    |     1 |
| banana   | yellow |     3 |
+----------+--------+-------+
```

The actual table has millions of entries and it currently takes a significant amount of time to query the database as the current procedure I am using is not very efficient:

Order the categories by the amount of entries in each category:

```
SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(CATEGORY) FROM FRUIT GROUP BY CATEGORY ORDER BY COUNT(CATEGORY);
```

Then for each category I list the relevant series in order of the series:

```
SELECT SERIES, COUNT(SERIES) FROM FRUIT WHERE CATEGORY = [current category] GROUP BY SERIES ORDER BY SERIES;
```

What would be the most efficient way to query the database (Preferably a single SQL statement) in order to get the desired output?

Comment: What about: `SELECT CATEGORY, SERIES, COUNT(*) FROM FRUIT GROUP BY CATEGORY, SERIES ORDER BY COUNT(*);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some shorter version:

```
select category, series, CntS 
from (
  select  distinct count(category) over (partition by category) cntC,
   count(series)  over (partition by category, series ) cntS,
   category, series 
from fruit   ) Tab
order by CntC desc, cntS desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by grouping on both `CATEGORY` and `SERIES`:

```
SELECT 
    CATEGORY, SERIES, COUNT(*) 
FROM FRUIT 
GROUP BY CATEGORY, SERIES 
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

---

UPDATE:

To order by total of `CATEGORY` first and then green, yellow, red, just like your expected output:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CATEGORY, SERIES, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM FRUIT 
    GROUP BY CATEGORY, SERIES 
) t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        CATEGORY, COUNT(*) AS CNT
    FROM FRUIT
    GROUP BY CATEGORY
) t2
    ON t1.CATEGORY = t2.CATEGORY
ORDER BY 
    t2.CNT DESC,
    CASE t1.SERIES
        WHEN 'green' THEN 1
        WHEN 'yellow' THEN 2
        WHEN 'red' THEN 3
    END
```

Comment: I have tried that, the output is then ordered by COUNT(SERIES) and not by COUNT(CATEGORY). My output is:                                              banana | yellow | 3; 
pear  | yellow | 3; 
pear       | green  | 2; 
apple | yellow | 2; 
apple | green | 1; 
apple | red  | 1